# Интеграция Selenium в BrowseEmAll

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь работать с браузером [BrowseEmAll](https://www.browseemall.com/) используя вот такой скрипт на Python 3.5:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("beabrowser", "IE7")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\BrowseEmAll\\BrowseEmAll.exe', chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get(r'sitename')
driver.quit()
```

И возникает у меня вот такая проблема:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\BrowseEmAll\\BrowseEmAll.exe', chrome_options = chrome_options)
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__ desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 91, in __init__ self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in start_session 'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">/HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Как исправить такую ошибку? Все что сами создатели пишут о взаимодействии браузера с selenium вот (и то на Java):

```
// Java example         
// This should either be
// C:\Program Files (x86)\BrowseEmAll\BrowseEmAll.exe or
// C:\Program Files\BrowseEmAll\BrowseEmAll.exe
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BrowseEmAll\\BrowseEmAll.exe");

// Now you need to tell BrowseEmAll the browser it should use to execute your test cases.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("beabrowser", "IE11");

// Now you can instantiate the driver like any other driver
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// You can use the driver like any other selenium driver:
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
element.sendKeys("TEST");
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то не так с запросом:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Возможно, стоит указать "sitename"?

> driver.get(r'sitename')